# javascript for loop and match strings

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with loops and comparisons with JSONObj. My code works except if the item does not exist in JSONObj.

I want to compare 2 string **JSONObj** with **res** does not exist give me a message in myTextarea2 like the input **BBB** does not exist

I tried boolen  `var isNomatch = ((JSONObj[i] == res[b]))`

`if (isNomatch == false)` I think this ide is wrong

or

`if((JSONObj[i] !== res[b])){`

and my for loop is odd

**Html head**

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="26B,26N,245">
<button onclick="myFunction()">ok</button>
<br>
<textarea  id="myTextarea">Item</textarea > 
<br> 
<textarea  id="myTextarea2"></textarea >
```

**Javascript**

```
var JSONObj = [
    {"nummer":"26B", "item":"26B) Sonic Screwdriver\n\n"},
    {"nummer":"26N", "item":"26N) Pizza\n\n"},
    {"nummer":"245", "item":"245) I need Coffe\n\n"}

]

  function myFunction(){
      var str = document.getElementById("myText").value;
      var res = str.split(",");

      for(var b = 0; b < res.length; b++) {

          for(var i = 0; i < JSONObj.length; i++) {

              //Here is the problem
              if((JSONObj[i] !== res[b])){
              var str2 = res[i]; 
              var text2 = [text2,str2].join("");
      document.getElementById("myTextarea2").value  =text2;
          }

          //this one's OK 
          if (JSONObj[i].nummer === res[b]){ 

              var str1 = JSONObj[i].item; 
              var text1 = [text1,str1].join("");
      document.getElementById("myTextarea").value  =text1;
      document.getElementById("myTextarea").cols = "100";
      document.getElementById("myTextarea").rows = "20";
       } 
      } 
     } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noted the part where there is a problem

```
//Here is the problem
      if((JSONObj[i] !== res[b])){
      var str2 = res[i]; 
      var text2 = [text2,str2].join("");

      }
```

**You are trying to compare if a object is not equal to a string** Which will always be `true`.

Change the syntax to

```
if(JSONObj[i].nummer !== res[b]){
```

---

I see another problem in your code. This part

```
 //this one's OK 
          if (JSONObj[i].nummer === res[b]){ 

              var str1 = JSONObj[i].item; 
              var text1 = [text1,str1].join("");
          }
```

is outside the for loop and how can you access the index value of `i` . Since you are saying its working, Either the code you posted here is not what you really have or your code is not working at all.

Comment: I use netBeans no error.  jsfiddle.net not working and jsbin out of scope for text1 and text1 . works weird